# Django: Serving CSS from S3 with correct URL but won't load

Tags: css, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I have set my STATIC_URL to the URL for my S3 bucket & static directory within it.

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXX/static/'
```

In my template, I am trying to load the stylesheets from :

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The stylesheet isn't getting loaded but when I view the source of the page, I can click on the link rendered for the stylesheet which downloads the correct file. Also the permissions are set to view World so it is accessible just won't load (even if I do a hard refresh in Chrome).

Why wouldn't the stylesheet load since the URL is correct?

Thanks in advance for your help-

Comment: This seems like an HTML problem, not anything Django-related, if the URL is actually right. Probably dumb, but could you try adding `type="text/css"` to the `<link>` tag? Also, double-check that your `<link>` is in `<head>`....

Comment: It is within <head> and adding the type unfortunately didn't do anything (HTML5). But thanks for the ideas

Comment: Is the stylesheet correctly formatted? An unclosed comment tag in it perhaps? You could try validating the html and css.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Firebug in Firefox. Hit F12 to open the Firebug window, click on the Net tab, and do a shift-reload. This will give you a blow-by-blow of all of the downloads. Click on the file you are having trouble with and it will give you all of the HTTP request/response headers. Enlightenment often follows soon after.

Answer (score 0):

From the Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/

The staticfiles contrib app ships with a static template tag which uses staticfiles' STATICFILES_STORAGE to build the URL of the given path. Use that if you have an advanced use case **such as using a cloud service to serve static files**:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" />
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap-responsive.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a `.css` file to S3, it will set the content type of the file to `binary/octet-stream`.

To fix the issue, follow this tutorial: http://log.adamwilcox.org/2012/05/04/css-on-amazon-s3/